# Selenium: Not able to understand xPath

Tags: html, selenium, screen-scraping, automated-tests

I have some HTML like this:

```
<h4 class="box_header clearfix">
<span>
<a rel="dialog" href="http://www.google.com/?q=word">Search</a>
</span>
<small>
<span>
<a rel="dialog" href="http://www.google.com/?q=word">Search</a>
</span>
</h4>
```

I am trying to get the href here in Java using Selenium. I have tried the following:

```
selenium.getText("xpath=/descendant::h4[@class='box_header clearfix']/");
selenium.getAttribute("xpath=/descendant::h4[@class='box_header clearfix']/");
```

But none of these work. It keeps complaining that my xpath is invalid. Can someone tell me what mistake I am doing?

Comment: If you've upgraded to Selenium 2 and are using ASP.NET Web Forms (which it looks like you are), you may benefit from some helper classes.  http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/simplifying-c-selenium-2-tests-for-asp-net-webforms/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use getAttribute to get the href of the link. Your XPath needs a reference to the final node, plus the required attribute. The following should work:

```
selenium.getAttribute("xpath=/descendant::h4[@class='box_header clearfix']/a@href");
```

You could also modify your XPath so that it's a bit more flexible to change, or even use CSS to locate the element:

```
//modified xpath
selenium.getAttribute("//h4[contains(@class,'box_header')]/a@href");

//css locator
selenium.getAttribute("css=.box_header a@href");
```

Comment: @Dave & @Legend: If you care about the speed of your tests, my advice would be to avoid such flexible xpath expressions (using // and similar). The reason is that Selenium by default uses a javascript XPath library which is _very_ slow (I'm talking about seconds here), especially if it needs to go through the whole HTML document in order to find something.

Comment: @Igor It's a balance of allowing your application to change somewhat without your tests failing, and your tests running faster. I generally prefer not to fix tests between application changes so don't mind the XPath taking a little bit longer. Of course you could also use CSS locators, which are faster and (generally) more flexible. :)

Comment: Thank You for the advice. This was just a testing for the testing app so I will keep that in mind. The ids and classnames are almost dynamically being generated so I was left with just XPath in the end...

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with Selenium and xpath in the past and couldn't really resolve it (other than changing the expression). Just to be sure I suggest trying your xpath expressions with the [XPath Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1095) addon for firefox.

Comment: Thanks. I will install that and check it Just to make sure I am on the right path, am I using XPath correctly with selenium? I mean which one should I use: getText or getAttribute?